# django model Charfield

Tags: django, django-models

If I want a CharField with only one digit is this the way to write the model

```
variable = model.CharField(max_length=1)
```

Or if you only have one Char it is a differnet field?

Thanks!

Comment: If it will contain single digit maybe Integer will be better? Or cahrfield with choices

Comment: @Ilian Iliev: If you want to add this as an answer I'll delete mine.

Comment: @llian: right. sorry it doesnt matter for me. I guess Integer would be cool aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid the hideous drop-down selection widget that gets generated for choice fields, you can do this.

Model:

```
variable = model.CharField(max_length=1)
```

Form:

```
def clean_variable(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data['variable']
    if data not in string.digits:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Not a digit")
    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one digit (integer) being used,

You can take a look at:
PositiveSmallIntegerField or SmallIntegerField

Answer (score 0):

```
variable = model.CharField(max_length=1)
```

This is perfectly fine. But as @[Ilian Iliev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/423283/ilian-iliev) noted it might be a good idea to tighten it up with choices

```
CHOICES = (('1', '1'), ..., ('10', '10')) # Simplified; you may want to add more, auto generate this list etc.
variable = model.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CHOICES)
```

You can also switch to an Integer field

```
CHOICES = ((1, '1'), ..., (10, '10')) 
variable = model.PositiveIntegerField(choices=CHOICES)
```

Comment: @S.Lott - Because I am a hasty idiot with failing eyesight. Corrected.

Comment: @S.Lott - See my first comment. Editing again.

Comment: Thanks. What if would like to have multiple Choices on Multiple fields?

variable1 = set of choices
variable2 = set of choices

etc..

How do I implement?

Answer (score 0):

Use IntegerField and the clean method that S.Lott show to check is value between 0 and 10